# Can't get Nginx to run under Docker environment on Windows for unknown reason

Tags: windows, docker, nginx, laradock

So, the last week or so I've been struggling trying to get my nginx server to run off of Docker/Laradock. The weird thing is that it worked when I was running it off C:/, but after being told by work that I had to encrypt my disk, I downloaded VeraCrypt and made an encrypted drive Y:/ and copied my vhosts folder into there.

After a lot of struggles trying to even get the `laradock_nginx_1` to attach, I followed [this guide](https://support.divio.com/local-development/docker/how-to-use-a-directory-outside-cusers-with-docker-toolboxdocker-for-windows), as I thought maybe Docker Toolbox didn't have access to the Y:/ drive. This seemed to work, but I still get a weird error when trying to get nginx up and running:

`Y:\vhosts\laradock>docker-compose up nginx
WARNING: The PHP_FPM_INSTALL_TOKENIZER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
laradock_workspace_1 is up-to-date
Starting laradock_docker-in-docker_1 ... done
Starting laradock_php-fpm_1          ... done
Starting laradock_nginx_1            ... done
Attaching to laradock_nginx_1
nginx_1                | /opt/startup.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
nginx_1                | /opt/startup.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file
laradock_nginx_1 exited with code 2`

Read somewhere else that the `\r` was simply the line ending of Windows. I tried to cd into `/opt/startup.sh`, but it didn't seem to exist. I found out that there was another `startup.sh` inside `laradock/nginx/`, I ssh'ed into the Docker VM and saw that every line ended with `^M`, which I suspect might've been `\r`. I removed those, but nothing really changed, still got the same problem.

While in ssh, I also did a hexdump of the startup bash file using `hexdump startup.sh | grep 0d0a`, but nothing came up. I'm at a loss for solutions, and not really sure what else I can try to do. Please note that Docker for Windows or BitLocker is out of the question since I only have Windows 10 Home.

What could I try to remedy this problem? Is this a known problem?

Answer (score 6):

You can try to convert `laradock\nginx\startup.sh` file's **windows style line endings** to **linux style line endings**, i.e. with Notepad++ ( Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix (LF) ).

Then try to start nginx container with rebuild option:

`docker-compose up --build nginx`

Comment: A big thanks, I was almost crying the last day for this issue.